# Only vertical part of a grid texture is showing?

Tags: texturing, shaders, texture-coordinates

I'm trying to texture something with a metal bar texture, but only the vertical stripes appear on the plane I'm applying the material to. Images are below:

The image I'm trying to apply

[image]

The result:

[image: The image I'm trying to apply]

My shader settings:
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you share your blend file? https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Make sure you apply the scale of your object, CTRL + A > Scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks very much as if..

You're using *Generated* space, which is  0-1 in along all the sides of the bounding-box of your object, oriented with the object axes.

The XY of that space is being interpreted by the *Image Texture* node as UV, and the Z is being ignored (0, throughout).

[image]

In *Generated* space, your plane mesh is a slice through the projected texture.

**TL;DR** If you want to use *Generated* space, rotate the plane in Edit Mode, so it lies in its object's  XY. Or, use a mapped UV.